# clientHeight in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, element

I have a table in HTML code.

I need to get height of that table using JavaScript, so

```
alert(document.getElementById('myTable').clientHeight);
```

returns a correct value in IE, but always returns 0 in FF.

How can I get the height of the table in Firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: Try offsetHeight or scrollHeight ...

Comment: Just tried, offsetHeight returns 0 and scrollHeight also retorns 0 in FF :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MDC says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight)

> `clientHeight` is a non-standard, HTML-specific property introduced in the Internet Explorer object model.

In Firefox, the [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) property contains the current pixel height of an element, so you can use something like:

```
var theHeight = element.clientHeight || element.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: element.clientHeight = 0, element.offsetHeight = 0 and element.clientHeight || element.offsetHeight also = 0 in FF

Comment: @ihorko: Are you sure you selected the correct table (and that it's added to the DOM)?

Comment: Seems it's because initially table has style display:none

Comment: @ihorko Your table won't have a height while it has a display of none, but if you remove the style then you should be able to measure its height.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried offsetHeight? See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Answer (score 1):

clientHeight works in my Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/sZ9eg/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe comeone can correct me here, but if you want to get the height of a specific element then why not just use

EDIT: this only works if the element has inline styles and a defined height

```
document.getElementById('myReputation').style.height;
```

Comment: @Jaitsu That property will be empty unless the TABLE has its height set by CSS explicitly which may not be the case.

Comment: I didn't set up the height for the table in css

Comment: @Jaitsu Also, I believe `style` is write-only. To read the vales, you have to use `window.getComputedStyle(table, null).getPropertyValue('height')`

Comment: If you set CSS height and run that code it does return the height property, but it obviously doesn't suit ihorko's requirements as they're not setting the height explicitly

Comment: Guys, that's because I have style='display:none'

Comment: @Šime Vidas that's strange, works for me on IE8 and Firefox 4.0

Comment: @Jaitsu I can't get it to work in any of my browsers (FF 3.6, FF4 beta, Chrome, Safari 5, Opera 11, IE9 RC, IE9 RC Compatibility View). It just does not work on my machine ...

Comment: is that with a CSS height? very peculiar

Comment: @Jaitsu I've figured it out: `elem.style` can only retrieve the inline styles of an element (the contents of the style attribute of the element in the HTML source code). Read here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html *Access the inline styles of element x. Styles defined in embedded, linked or imported style sheets are not reported.*

Comment: @Jaitsu To read the overall style, you have to use getComputedStyle() (and currentStyle for IE compatibility)

Comment: Ahh, my bad... I was sure I did it on an element with CSS styles. Must be a mistake. I'll edit the original answer so as to not mislead someone else.