# offsettop & clientHeight in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm updating a web page from being supported by I.E. to code that works in Firefox.

I have a section of code that positions some tables on the page in certain locations. It works in IE, but it seems that `.clientHeight .offsetTop .style.posTop` and `.style.posLeft` do not work in firefox. are there alternatives for the Firefox browser?

Here's the piece of code that I'm looking at:

```
   var tableHeight = table1.clientHeight;
    var yLocation = table2.offsetTop - tableHeight / 4;


    table3.style.posTop = Math.max(table2.offsetTop + 2);
    table3.style.posLeft = + table2.offsetLeft  + 80;
```

Comment: what if you change `table3.style.posTop` in `table3.style.top` (and `posLeft` in `left`)?

Comment: Use also offsetHeight instead of clientHeight: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041957/clientheight-in-firefox

Comment: The web developer's mantra: If it works in IE, but not Firefox (and Chrome/Safari/Opera), your code is wrong. Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, changing to style.top and syle.left didn't change anything.